# oracle login account created when install oraclexe11g

Tags: oracle

When i install oraclexe11g on my ubuntu16.04 and restart my system.

I have new oracle account.why it is created for me.

now i have 3 account.

1.oracle.

2.ubuntu.

3.guest.

can any body please explain it for me . and how to login into oracle

account.During installation process of oraclexe11g it asked me to provide

password for SYS or SYSTEM. but this password does not work.It only for start

oraclesql in terminal.

Comment: run `ls /home` and see if a home directory for oracle user is present.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I run (ls /home), but there is no directory for oracle user.
I use this link to install oracle : (file:///home/pseudo/Desktop/desktop/Installing%20Java,%20Oracle%2011g%20R2%20Express%20Edition%20and%20SQL%20Developer%20on%20Ubuntu%2064-bit.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't log into the `oracle account` it's a `system user account` created by the `oracle installer` and has no `home directory`. That means it's not for normal use like other `user accounts`.

You can only interact with the `oracle app` via the terminal or a `GUI` if that's available.

See `man useradd`:

```
-r, --system
           Create a system account.

           System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their numeric identifiers are
           chosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and
           their GID counterparts for the creation of groups).

           Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless of the default setting in
           /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the -m options if you want a home directory for a
           system account to be created.
```

Comment: Hmm, Thank you, George sir for responding me. I understand, now I feel good.

Comment: I have one more problem.
when I try to run most of the commands I got this error.          
                                     " E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".

and one more problem.

"/usr/bin/ucf: line 567: awk: command not found".

Please, George Sir help me.I do not want to reinstall my os .because lots of data and applications I installed previously.
Please help me to get out of these problems.I try most of the solutions but not succeed.

Comment: George sir I accept the answer, but I am new in this forum and I have only 11 reputations so they recorded my vote only.

Comment: Thanks, George Sir, In previous comments, I asked some problem, these problems due to the partially installed packages.I update using apt-get, now problem solved. Thanks .